# what is the use of access modifier

Tags: java

there is need to use access modifier in programming language ?
if we choose all members and methods as a private then what will be the output?

Answer (score 7):

See: [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)) (Wikipedia)

Of course you can declare all members and methods as private, but then you got yourself a pretty much useless class, since you can't access any of them from another class.

Answer (score 4):

Private is used for encapsulation (OOP) to hide the implementation.
Public declared methods provide the interface of a class.

If you would declare everything as private you couldn't use methods from other classes.
Which would make a class with methods like that quite useless.

Answer (score 2):

You need the access modifiers in order to control the accessibility of the methods/members. The moral is you should limit the accessibility to private as possible but still you cannot make all of them private.

Suppose you have a utility class that performs an useful operation for all the classes (Ex : logging). In that case all the classes should "see" the utility class and its members.Definitely you cant make everything private here. That is only a one example among hundreds.

Answer (score 2):

Access modifiers are used to control the visibility of fields and methods. Often we have good reasons to disallow usage of a method or a field for objects of other classes.

If you just started coding in Java and keep all your own code in one class, then you eventually might not need different access modifiers (except for the main method which *has* to be `public`). Access modifiers start to get important once your design becomes object oriented (= once you implement more then one classes).

[Here is a pointer to the corresponding articel in the official Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Answer (score 2):

The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class.

If you are using all the members and members are private then you can't have the access outside the class.

check this:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 2):

Access modifiers are used for encapsulation: they allow you to arrange your code in packages and classes, and have only an "official" public interface visible to the outside, while hiding the implementation details (which you want to do, so that you can later change it without telling anyone).

This is especially (only?) important, when you release code as a library for other programmers to use. Even if the code is only used in your own program, it helps to structure larger programs into several packages.

Making everything private makes no sense unless your program consists of only one class.
It is a reasonable default, however: Until you think some other class needs to call it, make the method private.

The default modifier in Java (if nothing is specified) is package-protected. This allows the method or field to be accessed from your own related code (i.e. code in the same package), while still hiding it from anyone else. It also is a reasonable default, or the natural upgrade path from private: Until code outside of the package needs to call it, make the method package-protected.

The more visible levels are protected (subclasses can see it), and public (everyone can see it). Before making something public or protected, think about the interface carefully, because it gets difficult to change it later.

Answer (score 2):

I agree,`private` is great as a rule of thumb for member fields.  However, the `private` modifier prohibits subclasses from accessing fields and methods.  If all methods and fields were `private`, subclasses would have nothing in common with their superclasses except their type.

It would also be difficult for one Object to be useful to another if all methods were not available.  It would be difficult to write even instantiate an `Object` if *all* methods, (including constructors) were private.

A better question for discussion would be: outside of `private` and `public`, why have `protected` and the `default` access modifiers.

Comment: If we had only private and public, we could not structure our code in packages: The default modifier hides access from outside the package. I'd be willing to discuss if we need "protected", though. It is quite nifty if you make use of subclassing a lot, I guess.

Comment: 'However, in Java, private limits accessibility to fields and methods for subclasses.' I suggest you reword that statement, it is confusing as stated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default access which will make the class usable in a package. It you make `private` no one can use it.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about accessibility of your class method or property I drew a table in attempt to make it easy to understand.

```
+----------------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
|Access Modifiers      | Same Package   |  Subclass       |  Other packages      |
|----------------------|----------------|-----------------|----------------------|
|public                |      Y         |       Y         |            Y         |
|                      |                |                 |                      |
|protected             |      Y         |       Y         |            N         |
|                      |                |                 |                      |
|no access modifier    |      Y         |       N         |            N         |
|                      |                |                 |                      |
|private               |      Y         |       N         |            N         |
|                      |                |                 |                      |
+----------------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's need for access modifiers otherwise they wouldn't have been added.

One of the most important features of object oriented programming and reusing your code. If you'd make everything private, you won't be able to do this and you'd have to write the code over and over again! Using the public or default access modifiers would let you use your code from other classes.

Answer (score 0):

The access to classes, constructors, methods and fields are regulated using access modifiers i.e. a class can control what information or data can be accessible by other classes. The main contribution of access modifier is for encapsulations, which is one of the OOPs concepts.

If you make all the members and methods private than you are making your code not accessible to other classes. In general you wont be able to reuse the functionalities and code that are already available.

Answer (score 0):

The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class.
The default modifier use within package.
The protected modifier specifies that member can accessed within package as well as inherited
at any level.

Answer (score 0):

All method and fields are access within class only, then does not access outside class even you inherit or accessing using object of that class.

Java containing four access specifier,

```
Public
Private
Protected
Default
```

Java having five non-access modifier

```
static
final
abstract
syncronised
volatile
```

Source : [Tutorial Data - Java Modifier](http://tutorialdata.com/java/javamodifier.html)